# Sort collection according to field in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm having a trouble finding how to do a query with MongoDB/Mongoid here. So I have a model `User`, that `has_many :scores`, `Score` being another model that has a `code` and a `value`. The `code` is unique in the scope of the `user`. For a given code I want to get the users, sorted by the `value` of the `score`.

Basically, what I want to do is something like : `User.where('scores.code' => code).order_by('scores.value')`, except it cannot be done like this. I tried several things, and I think the answer is related to `User.where(:scores.matches => {:code => code})`, but this does not return me anything, so I must be missing something here..

Thanks for your time, hope I was clear enough!

Comment: FYI, I remodeled to achieve what I want, but am still interested in the answer.

Comment: Hi, I am little confused with your question. You mentioned that code is unique per user. But your example 'User.where('scores.code' => code).order_by('scores.value')' implies that there are many users that share a code.

Comment: For a given code, a user will have 0 or 1 corresponding score. But other users can (and will) have scores for this level too. That's what I meant by 'unique in the scope of user'

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably what you want:

```
scores = Score.where('code' => code).order_by('value')
```

If you want to get the user (assuming that Score class has `belongs_to :user`), then you can do this:

```
users_that_matches_code = scores.map { |s| s.user }
```